# DCT Coefficient in MPEG2 Bitstream ISO/IEC standards

Tags: video, decode, codec, multimedia, mpeg

I am having difficulty parsing MPEG2 video bitstream. I have an encoded MPEG2 video in a binary file and I want to use one of the "Selective Encryption Algorithms" that encrypts only the "DC signs in intra-macroblocks".

Can you pelase help me fining DC Coefficients and AC Coefficient in a bitsream. I mean is there a specific header for that like the one the sequence start by of the picture,... etc

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you perchance referring to encryption techniques outlined in this paper? http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/iwnas/2006/2651/00/26510183-abs.html

Comment: @MultimediaMike actually there are many algorithms that addresses such techniques and this paper is one of them.

Comment: @MultimediaMike this paper is more clear into describing a close algorithm to what I am applying http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960077906003651#

Answer (score 1):

So, if this is about encrypting the DC coefficients, that means you have to write a parser to take apart the various bitstream syntax elements, encrypt the DC coefficient elements, and then pack up the entire bitstream again. It might be a bit of a chore, especially if you're not already familiar with bitstream parsers.

Alternatively, you could leverage and modify existing MPEG-2 parsers (check licenses, of course). That might make the task easier.

Comment: That's true regarding the parser. This is what I am going to be building. I am asking if there is a quick reference manual where I could figure out how to extract DC coefficients from a bit stream. Like this on for GOP,Picture, Slice,..., etc. http://www.mpucoder.com/DVD/mpeghdrs.html